# How to remove Linux dual boot with Windows10?

Tags: windows-10, linux-mint, uninstall, dualboot

I have a machine with dual boot where first OS installed was Windows 10 and after was installed Linux Mint.

In BIOS boot options I see Ubuntu and Windows, and when machine boots, appears grub menu.

In Grub menu appears:

```
Linux Mint
Other advance options
Windows 10
```

My question is:
If in Windows 10, from Disk Management, I delete the 3 partitions (boot, root, swap) that belong to Linux Mint would be a problem when I try to boot later in Windows?

I ask because I don't know if grub boot loader will be erased and I won't be able to boot in Windows10 anymore neither.

Thanks  in advance for any help/suggestion I'm how to remove Linux.

Regards

Comment: Simply deleting the partitions will leave your machine unbootable. There are many sites explaining how to do it correctly, e.g. https://itsfoss.com/uninstall-ubuntu-linux-windows-dual-boot/ . You question showed no effort to check online.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks for answer. I already did a research and with your information shared I hope reach my goal.